# two symbols (accidentals) on the same note

Tags: notation, accidentals

I'm having trouble learning Moonlight Sonata without a piano teacher.  What does a natural notation and a sharp symbol mean in front of the f, which is already sharp in the key signature?

Comment: Got a measure number? I'm checking. My guess is that it has something to do with a previous double sharp.

Comment: My guess is that it was an F## earlier in the measure and now it's an F# instead and the natural is to cancel the second sharp and the first is to remind you F's are still sharp.

Answer (score 7):

I can't find it in the edition I'm looking at, but probably this is a courtesy accidental to make it easier to remember what note you're playing.

Strictly speaking, courtesy accidentals aren't needed for any theory reason, but they can make a difference when playing. Usually they are found at the start of a measure canceling the accidental in the previous measure. They are up to the editor since they don't affect the playing of the music, and vary between editions.

In c♯ minor, fx is the leading tone to the dominant (g♯), so it occurs pretty frequently. To remind you when you're looking at a "regular" f♯ after a passage of fxs, you could see a natural and then a sharp.

Answer (score 2):

It means that you are going from a double sharp to a sharp.

In classical notation for instance when you write a melodic minor scale with a double sharp going up and just a regular sharp going down you use a natural sign followed by a sharp to indicate the E## is going back to a E#.

Comment: I would add the word "Usually" to your first sentence. :-)